# Substituir switch case por IF else

Tags: c, c++, dev-c++

Gostaria de saber como posso substituir por IF else essa parte do código que está usando o switch case:

```
  switch (op)
   {
 case '1':
    inserir();
    break;      
case '2':
    relatorio ();
    break;
case '3':
    exit(0);
    break;
    
default:
    printf("\n");
    menu();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Pode sim, a diferença vai ser na complexidade da leitura.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, a substituição é a seguinte:

```
´´´

if (op == '1')
   inserir();
else if (op == '2')
   relatorio();
else if (op == '3')
   exit(0);
else
    printf("\n");
    menu();

´´´
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).